# About interfaces in Go

Tags: go

```
type IA interface {
    Method()
}

type SA struct {
}

func (this *SA) Method() {

}


func main() {
    var i IA = SA{} //error 
    var i IA = &SA{} //ok
    var obj = SA{}

    obj.Method()//ok     

}
```

Could you explain why does GO automatically dereference in the case of calling function (`obj.Method()`) but in assignment to interface variable (`var i IA = SA{}`) it can't?

Comment: Because the function expects a pointer (`*SA`) to a memory address. That's why `&SA{}` works, because you give it a memory-address.

Comment: Yes, but I asked why in the case of calling function GO does some underground (maybe puts obj from stack to heap and call with pointer). Maybe it can do the same things in the case of assignment, to store only pointer in interface variable?

Comment: This http://golang.org/doc/faq#different_method_sets answers your question.

Comment: Yes, yours link addresses my question entirely, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`func (this *SA) Method()` means that only a pointer to type `SA` (`*SA`) has the `Method()` method, therefore `var i IA = &SA{}` fulfils the `IA` interface.

If you change it to read `func (this SA) Method()` then `var i IA = SA{}` fulfils the interface, and not `var i IA = &SA{}`.

`*SA` is not the same type as `SA`.

Go provides some shortcuts for dealing with dereferencing method values (which is probably where the confusion is coming from)

If you have a look at the [Method Values section of the spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_values) you will see that:

> a reference to a non-interface method with a value receiver using a pointer will automatically dereference that pointer

and

> a reference to a non-interface method with a pointer receiver using an addressable value will automatically take the address of that value

This is why `obj.Method()` works whether `obj` is an `*SA` or an `SA`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. But I didn't ask about why is it error.I asked why it can't be dereferenced  var  i IA = SA{} automatically by GO compiler

Comment: because `SA{}` doesn't satisfy the `IA` interface.